# Multiple magento frontend servers and one Redis session cache

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, varnish, cm-redissession

Right now I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 with Redis Session Storage. I am looking forward to adding additional frontend server behind a load balancer. Can I use the same Redis server for sessions for both frontend servers?

Idea:

```
Server1 = Apache + PHP + Redis
Server2 = Apache + PHP + Database
```

Varnish listens for connections and uses Server1 or Server2 to handle misses and esi stuff

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provided you are using Redis over TCP and not via a local socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conlinmollenhour extension for redis session in magento (if you have magento 1.8 and up this is included)
Point both session configuration in app/etc/local.xml to the same redis server and same db (make sure the  parameter in the redis configuration are the same)

for server 1

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <db>0</db>
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
            <log_level>1</log_level>
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
        </redis_session>
        ...
    </global>
    ... </config>
```

for server2

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>
            <host>internal ip of server 1</host>
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <db>0</db>
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
            <log_level>1</log_level>
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
        </redis_session>
        ...
    </global>
    ... </config>
```